# PHP unique values from fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysqli, unique

I have a product database and each product has 1 or more tags. For example, my query result is:

```
//Query results
product_id  tag
12345       Kitchen
12345       Mixer
12345       Baking
```

How can I display all the tags for a given product and only list the product once so that my output is something like:

```
Product ID: 12345 
Tags: Kitchen Mixer Baking
```

Currently, I'm using `fetch_assoc()` and looping through the rows which just displays everything. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Below is my current code:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT p.product_id, t.tag
    FROM products p
    JOIN tags t
    ON p.product_id = t.product_id
    WHERE p.product_id='12345'
SQL;

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['product_id'] . '<br>';
    echo $row['tag'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT p.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag)
FROM products p
JOIN tags t
ON p.product_id = t.product_id
WHERE p.product_id='12345'
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks! That was simple enough.